# How do you see if adjacent elements repeat in a list? (SML)

Tags: list, element, sml, ml

SML is a challenging language for me to learn. I'm trying to find a way to screen an undetermined list and return a boolean based on whether two elements adjacent on a list are the same value or not. What I've tried and think is close to correct is below.

```
fun repeatE nil = false
  | repeatE (first::last) = first = last orelse repeatsE(last);
```

Obviously, this results in an error. I based my answer on this code, which tells me if a value is an element in the list.

```
fun member (e, nil) = false
  | member (e, first::last) = e = first orelse member(e, last);
```

Why does the first one not work, but the last one does? It tells me that the operator and the operand don't agree, and maybe I'm thick-headed, but I don't quite understand why they don't?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

`first=last` tries to compare the first element of a list with the tail of that list, and you can only compare things of the same (comparable) type.

The working code works because it doesn't try to compare a list element to an entire list.

You need to compare the first element to the second element, and you need to handle the case of a singleton list.

Something like this:

```
fun repeats nil = false
  | repeats (first::rest) = case rest of 
                               (x::xs) => first = x orelse repeats rest
                           |   _ => false
```

or

```
fun repeats nil = false
  | repeats (first::rest) = not (null rest)
                            andalso (first = (hd rest) orelse repeats rest)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's actually possible to use `as` to clean up @molbdnilo's answer a fair bit.

Ask yourself: An empty list is `false`, but so is a list with a single element, right?

```
fun repeats([])  = false
  | repeats([_]) = false
```

Now, we need to match a list with at least two elements, and compare those. If they're not equal, we'll check everything *but* the first element.

```
fun repeats([])  = false
  | repeats([_]) = false
  | repeats(a::b::tail) =   
      a = b orelse repeats(b::tail)
```

But we don't need to use `b::tail`.

```
fun repeats([])  = false
  | repeats([_]) = false
  | repeats(a::(tail as b::_)) =   
      a = b orelse repeats(tail)
```

If we want, we can recognize that the empty list and the single element list are just the "other" when the last pattern doesn't match, and we'll rewrite it to reflect that.

```
fun repeats(a::(tail as b::_)) = 
      a = b orelse repeats(tail)
  | repeats(_) = false
```